# GridSearchCV : n_jobs in parallel (internals)

Tags: scikit-learn

How does GridSearchCV with n_jobs being set to a  >1 value actually work. Does it create multiple instances of the classifier for each node(computation node) or does it create 1 single classifier which is shared by all the nodes. The reason I am asking is becuase I am using vowpal_wabbits Python wrapper: https://github.com/josephreisinger/vowpal_porpoise/blob/master/vowpal_porpoise/vw.py and see that it opens a subprocess (with stdin, stdout, stderr etc). However when I use this from GridSearch with n_jobs > 1 , I get a broken pipe error after some time and am trying to understand why?

Comment: If you want to use n_jobs > 1 inside GridSearchCV then you have to protect the script using:  if __name__ == '__main__': . This little tip solved the same error for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n_jobs > 1` will make `GridSearchCV` use Python's multiprocessing module under the hood. That means that the original estimator instance will be copied (pickled) to be send over to the worker Python processes. All scikit-learn models MUST be picklable. If the `vowpal_porpoise` opens pipes to a vw subprocess in the constructor object, it has to close them and reopen them around the pickling / unpickling steps by defining custom `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods. Have a look at the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) for more details.

The subprocess should probably be close and reopened upon the call to the `set_params` method to update the parameters of the model with new parameter values.

It would be easier to not open the subprocess in the constructor and just open it on demand in the fit and predict methods and close the subprocess each time.

Comment: Which one is better, to use n_jobs=-1 or n_jobs with a big number like 32 ?!

Answer (score 1):

One of the Questions in the comments was is

> Which one is better, to use n_jobs=-1 or n_jobs with a big number like 32 ?!

This depends on your understanding of *better*. I would say, that this depends on your hardware currently available as well as how much you want to provide of it to the algorithm.

The [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) says that `n_jobs=-1` uses all processors (for instance threads). Therefore, if your hardware actually supports 32 Threads, the function `GridSearchCV()` will use 32 of the processors. And if you decrease the number further (`n_jobs=-2`, `n_jobs=-3` and so forth) you will allocate the number of possible processors minus the number you decreased the parameter. As an example when 8 jobs would be possible, then 7 jobs will be instanciated when `n_jobs=-2`.

But it is also a little bit more complicated than this: The number of jobs specified with `n_jobs` in `GridSearchCV()` does not have to be identical to the actual threads used by Python because there may be other sources that use processors [2](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html?highlight=jobs#why-does-my-job-use-more-cores-than-specified-with-n-jobs).